# CakePHP3: how to log in as another user

Tags: cakephp-3.0

As administrator, I'd like to take another identity to access the backoffice as a normal user.

So I select a user in a list and submit it to my controller.

I tried the following code but I never access to target url, I receive HTTP code 302 as If I tried to access the url, without any user logged in.

What's the problem?

```
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));

    if (($user['role'] == 'admin') && (!empty($this->request->data))) {

        $id = $this->request->data['id'];

        if (!$this->Users->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
        }

        $user = $this->Users->findById($id);
        $this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());

        return $this->redirect([
            'controller' => 'Owners', 
            'action' => 'account', 
            'prefix' => 'pros'
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oups, I found my stupid error:

```
$user = $this->Users->findById($id)->first();
```